# How to resolve jq error "Cannot index number with string" when document is followed by a number?

Tags: bash, jq

I am doing a `curl` call to a server from a `bash` script. In the response I want to extract some data using `jq`. but, I am getting below error from `jq`

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index number with string "_links"
```

Part of script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

keyword="config"

response=$(curl --location "${HEADERS[@]}" -s -w "%{http_code}\n" -X GET "$url")

if echo ${response} | grep "$keyword" ; then
    extract=$(jq -r "._links" <<< "${response}")
    echo "$extract"
fi
```

The actual response:

```
{
    "config": {
        "polling": {
            "sleep": "00:20:00"
        }
    },
    "_links": {
        "deployment": {
            "href": "https://www.example.com"
        },
        "configData": {
            "href": "https://www.example.com/configData"
        }
    }
}
200
```

Can anyone please let me know what is the issue here?

Thanks in advance

P.S: I am testing on Ubuntu (on WSL). please let me know if any info is missing

Comment: Works for me when I put the response in a file and run `jq -r "._links" < response.json`. It prints everything under "_links". Can you make a [mcve] without the (undefined) url?

Comment: The `200` is a problem. It's a number. `.config` or `._links` doesn't make sense with a number.

Comment: BTW, `set -e` [is a bad idea](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105). At minimum, review the exercises section of the linked FAQ; it's much more reliable to put `|| exit` or `|| return`, as appropriate, after each command that you want to cause an abort on failure.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yea that's correct. This was just a initial version of my script. It will be updated. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: BTW, think about `if [[ $response = *keyword* ]]` instead of the `echo | grep` pipeline. Avoids bugs like those described in [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else), and if your document isn't huge it'll be quite a lot faster since it doesn't need to start a separate grep executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input has a JSON document followed by other content, you can make your jq only read that one input:

```
extract=$(jq -n "input | ._links" <<<"$response")
```

The `-n` tells jq not to read anything by default; the `-n`, used exactly once, tells it to read one thing.

---

You could also extract *both* the `_links` attribute *and* the HTTP status code with just one invocation of jq:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' extract http_code < <(
  jq -nc '
    input as $full_doc | input as $status_code |
    (($full_doc | ._links), $status_code)
  ' <<<"$response" && printf '\0'
)
```

Using `read -d ''` causes `read` to fail if it doesn't find a NUL at the end of input, and the `&& printf '\0'` adds a NUL at the end of the [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst)'s output if `jq` reports success.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. `extract=$(jq -n "input | ._links" <<<"$response")` adds quotes `""` to the output..But adding `| tr -d '"'` worked

Comment: @Preeti use `-r` if you don't want the quotes when evaluating to a string, but the format of your sample input JSON says `._links` is not a string but instead a dictionary/map/object, so `-r` won't do anything unless your real JSON format is different from the one you showed us. The other thing is that `-r` is a bit of a security risk in the case where we use `-c` and assume single-line output for each entry.

Comment: @Preeti (are you really extracting something different, like `._links.deployment.href`, but just shortened for the question? When you said just `._links`, that has a _meaning_ in the context of your sample data, which is why it appeared that `-r` was being used unnecessarily/inappropriately).

Comment: You can do `jq -nc 'input|._links, input'`

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `response` does *not* contain what you have shown. The actual content of the variable is:

```
{
    "config": {
        "polling": {
            "sleep": "00:20:00"
        }
    },
    "_links": {
        "deployment": {
            "href": "https://www.example.com"
        },
        "configData": {
            "href": "https://www.example.com/configData"
        }
    }
}
200
```

That `200` is added to the output because you call `curl -w "%{http_code}\n"`, which will add the response status code to the output. If you plan on processing the output, get rid of the `-w` option (you are not parsing it with jq, so you don't need it).

If you require `200` to be part of the output, then you could instruct jq to read the full input into a single array and only operate on the first item:

```
jq -s 'first._link' <<< "$response"
```

But in that case, I recommend going with Charles Duffy's answer and use `-n` in combination with `input`.

Comment: Hello @knittl, thanks for the update. Yes, that was the issue. But I don't want to get rid of `-w "%{http_code}\n"`. This will be used later to check http status...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes not by `jq`. For example to check if response code is 200 before doing `jq`

Comment: You could, if you chose, make the jq be the thing that processes the 200. Otherwise you end up doing something relatively messy like running a separate copy of `tail`.